# Invalid Referencing Name in SQL regardless of name

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need some help with a SQL trigger that I am trying to create. I keep getting the error

> ORA - 04074: invalid REFERENCING name

which, from what I looked up, is a sign that the referencing name I am giving is a keyword, but I have used multiple names and always run into the same error.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CatchSightInserts
AFTER INSERT ON SIGHTINGS
REFERENCING NEW ROW AS nrw
WHEN (nrw.LOCATION IN (SELECT LOCATION
                       FROM FEATURES
                       WHERE CLASS = 'SUMMIT'))
PRINT 'An invalid entry was inserted.'
END
/
```

I have also tried to change line 3 to

```
REFERENCING NEW ROW AS NewRow
```

in case if it was the name causing the problems, but the error persisted. I am relatively new to SQL so any help at all would be extremely valuable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no `print` statement in PL/SQL.

Comment: I am using the DBMS Output Package though which, I was led to believe would support the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is PL/SQL.

The syntax for referencing would be:

```
REFERENCING NEW AS nrw
```

Without "ROW".

As Farheg states you are missing FOR EACH ROW and print is not what you want. You probably would have to raise an exception. But that's a guess.
Read about the syntax (11g):
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much.  I am now getting an error on the line with the subquery, the error being ORA-02251: subquery not allowed here. Do you by any chance know what would cause that? I'm sorry if these questions seem trivial but I can't find any good answers to them online and am too new to relational databases to really be able to figure it out.

Comment: Well, instead of the "WHEN" clause I would use declare/begin/end. You can find countless examples if you use google. Like http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Trigger/CreateatriggerwithREFERENCINGnewAS.htm

Comment: yes, the `ROW` also is extra, I didn't notice it too

Answer (score 1):

you missed a `BEGIN` word and also `FOR EACH ROW` that I think you need it, also you missed a semicolon `;` after the print command (am not sure if exists in Oracle) and also after `END`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CatchSightInserts
AFTER INSERT ON SIGHTINGS
REFERENCING NEW ROW AS nrw
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (nrw.LOCATION IN (SELECT LOCATION
                       FROM FEATURES
                       WHERE CLASS = 'SUMMIT'))
BEGIN
PRINT 'An invalid entry was inserted.';
END;
/
```

Comment: The problem seems to be root from the use of PL/SQL instead of SQL. I assumed that the commands were identical for my purposes but I guess it isn't so sorry about the confusion. I did make the corrections you pointed out as well and am actually running into a new problem. I am now getting an error on the line with the subquery, the error being ORA-02251: subquery not allowed here. Do you by any chance know what would cause that? I'm sorry if these questions seem trivial but I can't find any good answers to them online and am too new to relational databases to really be able to figure it out.

Comment: oh you are right, I didn't notice the statement inside while, let me to review it

Comment: I think in fact you need an `if` statement, however you know the situation better, see the samples